# Retrieving table name and/or column name via QueryDSL?

Tags: java, querydsl

Is there any way in QueryDSL to retrieve the table name and/or column name for an entity from the `Q` classes?  I've looked through the classes and can't find anything offhand, but I figure there must be a way for QueryDSL to know the table names.

Comment: Are you talking about Querydsl JPA or SQL?

Comment: QueryDSL JPA.  Sorry - forgot there was that distinction.

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like `QMyTable.myAttribute.path.getMetadata().getName()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querydsl does not know/care about the table names in Querydsl JPA. It serializes the queries into JPQL where classes and properties are used instead of tables and columns.

If you need the SQL model you can use Querydsl SQL instead or inspect the JPA metamodel via the JPA API.

Comment: Any suggestions / recommendations where/how to inspect the JPA metamodel via the JPA API?  I looked for documentation on that but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You access the metamodel via entityManager.getMetamodel: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Too late response, but might help someone else.
You can try the MetaDataExporter.

```
java.sql.Connection conn = ...;
MetaDataExporter exporter = new MetaDataExporter();
exporter.setPackageName("com.myproject.mydomain");
exporter.setTargetFolder(new File("target/generated-sources/java"));
exporter.export(conn.getMetaData());
```